# ARM .ELF size Debug options

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, arm, embedded

Not too long ago I updated our ARM compiler 
(Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013) to slightly more recent version (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2015).

This caused some strange differences in our output. I use the .elf files mainly for debugging purposes (combined with GDB) and with some automatic test scripts it is possible to check a lot of variables in a short time.
Now the problem:

```
Size of the .elf of the old compiler: 35MB

Size of the .elf with the new compiler: 2.2MB
```

This obliviously a massive difference, and next to the compiler update nothing changed here, and the small sized .elf file is a lot slower to read and this is becoming an issue.

The Sourcery Codebench change-logs didn't help too much, but I do know the old version is based on GCC version 4.7.3, and the new one on >GCC 4.8.3. 
I have been looking around for while now, but I can't find the change in the compiler that causes this different output.

The software is build with arm-none-eabi and
for debugging the following options are enabled:

```
-g3 
-gdwarf-2
```

The makefile so far as I can share it, let me point out this file is already alive for a long long time:

```
EXT_LIBS := \
    -lm

cppflags := \
    $(CONFIGFLAGS) \
    -UUSE_FULL_ASSERT \
    -DADC_IN_HAL_IO \

cflags := \
    $(cpu_flags) \
    $(cppflags) \
    $(cc_board_flags) \
    $(INCLUDES) \
    -O0 \
    -Wall \
    -Wno-comment \
    -Wno-unused-but-set-variable \
    -c \
    -fmessage-length=0 \
    -mthumb \
    -g3 \
    -gdwarf-2


asflags := \
    $(cpu_flags) \
    $(cppflags) \
    $(as_board_flags) \
    $(INCLUDES) \
    -Wall \
    -c \
    -fmessage-length=0 \
    -mthumb \
    -g3 \
    -gdwarf-2

lnkflags := \
    $(lnk_board_flags) \
    $(INCLUDES) \
    -T$(SRC_LD) \
    -Wl,-Map,$(PROJECT).map \
    $(cpu_flags) \
    -mthumb \
    -g3 \
    -gdwarf-2 

    od_flags := \
    --dwarf
```

Edit for comments:
Both of the files give me the following when using `file`:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB Executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

Map files asked for:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58946673/Old_compiler.map

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58946673/New_Compiler.map

Does anyone know how to increase the .elf file to the old (large) format again?

Comment: It smells like old one was linking with static libs while the new one is linking with shared libs....

Comment: Definitely possible, is there any way of compiling it like this again? (Compile settings) Anything is worth a try to be honest.

Comment: Could you share the [tag:makefile] or resulting [tag:gcc] command used?

Comment: Added what I can share in the question

Comment: try to run `ldd` or `file`  commands for both files an add an output to the question (it will check  @LPs's suggestion)

Comment: Added output in the edit, both say to be statically linked.

Comment: Well, both projects links statically all libs, but haow about linked libs? The update performed is delivered with new libs? Maybe something changed on that side. Could you compare/look into map files to see what is missing the new one?

Comment: Mapping seem to be completely different, the map file of the new compiler surprisingly also has twice the size of the old one..

Comment: Try to share those files, if possible. We'll take a look at them.

Comment: Map files shared in question

Comment: It seems to me that a lot of optimization is performed in the new one. Maybe something changed as default by new compiler. For example, `ibs_op.o` was `0x4ae4` while the new one is `0x42ac`: more than 2K less. And the same for all other modules.

Comment: Alright, but we are talking about a 32MB difference here, not to forget the speed of the small one is a lot lower. Like an entire lookup-table is available in the first one. Some optimizations shouldn't decrease it by a factor 16 should it?

Comment: @koldewb In what circumstances is the smaller ELF "slower to read"? Is this under GDB, or do your test scripts do their own ELF parsing? If the former, are you comparing like-for-like using the exact same GDB (from the old toolchain or elsewhere), or might it just be down to differences between the GDB version provided by each toolchain?

Comment: @Notlikethat It is under GDB, and the exact same version of GDB is used.  The large elf file will take around 0.5 seconds to execute the script (Just some parse/read towards a specific GDB.exe terminal) and the small elf easily takes up to 10 seconds.

Comment: OK, from a quick look around, there do seem to be complaints about GDB 7.6 (and possibly others) being pathologically slow at symbol lookup under very particular circumstances - possibly the different ELF layout (or some other subtlety that's beyond me) could be provoking that?

Comment: Seems like we have a winner. Changed some versions around, on 1 version the big/small elf made a huge difference, on the other one no problem at all, not the problem I expected..

Answer (score 0):

The smaller ELF seems directly correlated with the larger map file, when you take into account this part of the latter:

```
...

Discarded input sections

 .group         0x00000000        0x8 can.o
...
```

The new linker has seen fit to throw out a whole heap of stuff that it thinks it doesn't need. Chances are that it has `--gc-sections` in effect by default, and these parts are (or at least appear to be) unreferenced. Since the rest of the symbols and section layout looks roughly the same between the two builds, it would appear that this is the case - if keeping megabytes of apparently unnecessary ELF sections around really has hidden benefits to you, try passing `--no-gc-sections` in the link options.

It's *possible* there might be other reasons, such as section names which aren't caught by an explicit linker script rule, and the two linkers having different default behaviour configured for what to do with those, but I'd definitely investigate the most obvious culprit first.

Comment: --no-gc-sections doesn't seem to be supported by the compiler. Only in a 
-Wl,--no-gc-sections format it actually compiles but doesn't have any effect on the .elf

Comment: --no-gc-sections is an instruction to the linker rather than the compiler.  If you invoke the linker via the compiler rather than directly, then you need the -Wl, prefix to pass it through.